# Removing non native customizer settings from a child theme

Tags: theme-development, customization, child-theme

For removing settings, controls and sections of the customizer, we can just simply use the remove methods like this:

```
function remove_custom($wp_customize) {
  $wp_customize->remove_setting('id');
  $wp_customize->remove_control('id');
  $wp_customize->remove_section('id');
}
```

What I notice is that there's no way to remove parent-theme customization, so non native customization of Wordpress itself.
In fact, trying to remove the `blogdescription` is possible.

I can't find documentation about that. What am I ignoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing a lot about how your themes work but, [the child theme's `functions.php` runs *before* the parent theme's `functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php), so anything loaded by the parent's functions isn't going to be present for you to remove. You need to hook your function so that it runs later.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_custom');
```

Though you would need to mess about with the `$wp_customize` variable. It would be easier to hook into the `customize_register` hook with a high priority number so that your code runs after the parent registration code.

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'remove_custom', 1000 );
```

Comment: Oh my god, it was that so. Yes I was already hooking to customize_register, so I added now the prioririty and it's working! Thank you.